# Fibonacci (non recursive) panics after 47th term

Tags: rust, fibonacci

I am writing a program to calculate Fibonacci series non recursively. Nothing fancy. The program runs, but panics at the 47th term, then terminates. Here's the error:

```
.
.
.
count 45 - fib - 701408733
count 46 - fib - 1134903170
count 47 - fib - 1836311903
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow', src\main.rs:20:23
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\fib.exe 50` (exit code: 101)
```

Up to 46, it works. So if I do `cargo run 46`, it work. Any number above it, it panics.

I wonder what's wrong. Here's the code:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect(); //Taking the range from the user

    let mut a: u32 = 0;
    let mut b: u32 = 1;
    let mut count: u32 = 0;

    let range: u32 = args[1].parse().unwrap(); // Converting input String to (unsigned) int

    if range <= 0 {
        println!("Please enter positive number greater than 0 please");
    } else if range == 1 {
        println!("{}", args[1])
    } else {
        while count < range {
            println!("count {} - fib - {}", count+1, &a);
            let nth = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = nth;
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the error message : `panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow'`
It means that your next fibonnaci number is so big that it do not fit in an `u32`. Would work if you use `u64` or any bigger integer size.
Check the limits for each number in the documentation.

Comment: FAKK. OK thanks. I have managed to embarrass myself again